# KCFinder upload file size limit

Tags: php, javascript

In my php.ini i verified that upload limit is 20M

However, when i try to upload files it accepts everything under approximately 120kb and refuses everything above that.

I didn't make any specific changes on kcfinder.

If it is important, i use Firefox and Chrome.

Any idea what can be problem?

Answer (score 1):

file uploads are affected with more variables than `upload_max_filesize` alone. File upload is just `POST` request, so you need to check `post_max_size` too and adjust it if needed. In general you want `post_max_size` to be at least the size `upload_max_filesize` + some overhead for other POST data.

Comment: I did it too, it's > post_max_size 8M

Comment: it seems that the limit is "130736" bytes :( what the hack is this :(

Comment: When i try to watch it in Firebug, if i try to upload bigger file than ~127b i get this: "ReferenceError: get_path is not defined"

otherwise i get no errors

Comment: do `phpinfo();` and see what are **local** settings for you script environment

Comment: I did it but i can't identify what actually to look fore.
It's really strange what ever the problem is. Because upload works fine up to certain file size.

php's upload limit and other settings seems to be ok.

I also tested on another hosting and it works perfectly :(

Here you can see what i get in Firebug debug: http://postimage.org/image/3m47ndl4j/

p.s. i added fullsize jquery so it detected the line where it fails.

i believe it's something on the line php to js...

Comment: it seems that the problem is within ispCP believe or not :( it returns some stupid error page and that mess up all :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution, but first, what did i try and got while i was exploring the issue:

- in php.ini everything seemed ok
- I noticed that i cant upload files larger than certain size, approximately ~127 kb
- Through the browser i could not understand easily what was wrong so in my case first that i noticed that it had to be something on server side.
- In my case i'm using ispCP control panel (not very happy with it) and ispCP have certain default error 400, 401.html, 403.html, 404.html, 500.html, 503.html pages that even have some stupid JS "" with "get_path()" function, which was reported as "the one causing the problem" via browser (FireBug). Since i was confused for few hours, i removed all those error pages and than i noticed that i have another "error" in (FireBug). But this time i was able to notice it is Server side error 500
- I immediately understood that i need to look into /var/log/apache2/... error log files.
- message there was: [Wed Sep 12 05:05:47] [warn] [client 12 05:05:47] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 135279 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072), referer: http://u-r-l--to--script.php?type=images&dir=
- so i "$ apache2ctl -M" and i found that module on the list "fcgid_module (shared)"
- in case someone is not familiar with apache modules, usually config files for apache modules are located here: "/etc/apache2/mods-available/..." mine one as you saw was "fcgid.conf" (there is also corresponding "*.load" file for every module).
- So i added two config lines there:

  FcgidMaxRequestLen 52428800

  MaxRequestLen 52428800

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart AND IT WORKED :D